# Formatting float elements to be on the same level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive been having trouble writing a concept design for my internship, im going for a page with six clickable elements (which are pictures) . Once one is clicked, the others disappear and the active one gets moved to the top. Ive gotten all this to work by using left positioning and jquery. however with the left positioning, the elements would move around with different screen resolutions. so i decided to use floats instead so there positions would be constant. i need the elements tht are floating left to be lined up vertically with the floats that are aligned right. Here is a screenshot of how it currently looks. [click here](http://min.us/mblT4Bs0SF) and this is how i want it to look. [finished look](http://minus.com/mOkCEEDGq#2)

Here is my current code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Div Blocks</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
        background: url(bgp.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

}
div.sep {

clear: both;

}


div.full
{
left:50%;
height:auto;
width:auto;

}

    a{
    cursor : url("nav.png"), pointer;
    }

  div.one a
{

top:50px;
float:left;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("branding.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:35px;
}
div.one a:hover
{background: url("brandingalt.png");

 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.one a:active
{background: url("brandingalt.png");

 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.two a
{

top:264px;
float:left;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("marketing.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:35px;
}
div.two a:hover
 {background: url("marketingalt.png");

 background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
div.three a
{

top:457px;
float:left;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("ecommerce.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
div.three a:hover
 {background: url("ecommercealt.png");

background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.r1 a
{

top:50px;
float:right;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("webdesign.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:25px;
}
div.r1 a:hover
 {background: url("webdesignalt.png");

background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.r2 a
{

top:254px;
float:right;
width: 450px;
height: 150px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("optimization.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
div.r2 a:hover
 {background: url("optimizationalt.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.r3 a
{

top:457px;
float:right;
width: 400px;
height: 75px;
text-decoration:none;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background:url(packaging.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.r3 a:hover
 {background: url("packagingalt.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>




    <div class="one">
<a href="#" value="Branding" class="go" ></a>
    </div><div class="sep"></div>
  <div class="r1">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div><div class="sep"></div>

    <div class="two">
<a href="#" class="go"></a>
    </div><div class="sep"></div>

      <div class="r2">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div><div class="sep"></div>


    <div class="three">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div><div class="sep"></div>

<div class="r3">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div><div class="sep"></div>





    </body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from changing the location
    $(this)
        .closest("div") // select the parent div of the link

        .siblings() // select all the siblings of the div
        .hide("slow") // hide them
setTimeout(function() {

$(".go").animate({top: "0"}, "slow");},1500);

});
```

Here is my old code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Div Blocks</title>

<style type="text/css">
html {
        background: url(bgo.jpg) no-repeat fixed center center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;



}

    a{
    cursor : url("nav.png"), pointer;
    }

  div.one a
{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:60px;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("branding.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:35px;
}
div.one a:hover
{background: url("brandingalt.png");
 background-position: 0px 0px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.one a:active
{background: url("brandingalt.png");
 background-position: 0px 0px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.two a
{
position: absolute;
top:264px;
left:60px;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("marketing.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:35px;
}
div.two a:hover
 {background: url("marketingalt.png");
 background-position:0px 0px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
div.three a
{
position: absolute;
top:457px;
left:56px;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("ecommerce.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
div.three a:hover
 {background: url("ecommercealt.png");
background-position: 0 0px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.r1 a
{
position: absolute;
top:50px;
left:900px;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("webdesign.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:25px;
}
div.r1 a:hover
 {background: url("webdesignalt.png");
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.r2 a
{
position: absolute;
top:254px;
left:900px;
width: 450px;
height: 150px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("optimization.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
div.r2 a:hover
 {background: url("optimizationalt.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.r3 a
{
position: absolute;
top:457px;
left:900px;
width: 400px;
height: 75px;
text-decoration:none;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background:url(packaging.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.r3 a:hover
 {background: url("packagingalt.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>



    <div class="one">
<a href="#" value="Branding" class="go" ></a>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
<a href="#" class="go"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>

    <div class="r1">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>
      <div class="r2">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>

            <div class="r3">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>




    </body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from changing the location
    $(this)
        .closest("div") // select the parent div of the link

        .siblings() // select all the siblings of the div
        .hide("slow") // hide them
setTimeout(function() {

$(".go").animate({top: "0"}, "slow");},1200);

});



</script>
```

If it would be easier to fix the old code to make the elements constant that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix (that I don't really prefer) would be to use *right* floats, and reverse the order in your markup. Part of the specification for floating essentially states that following floated elements must never be vertically above the preceding floated element.

However, I don't think floating is what you want at all. You would be better off using `display: inline-block` for these elements. Better still, if you can afford to support just modern browsers, using a table layout (`display: table/table-cell`, not *table elements*) would make this really easy.

Comment: could you got a little more in detail on how to use the (display: table/table-cell)

Comment: before i try to recode the entire thing i have a few questions,
1. would i be able to use a hover effect to change the image
2. would i still be able to use a jquery function to hide the elements and raise one of them to the top when clicked?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. To be sure, you did catch my caveat about `display:table` only working in modern browsers, right?

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with your code, but I had to remove and clean up a bunch of stuff so I'm not 100% sure if this is what you wanted. But here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/587RS/1/) using only left floats.

I think it might look better (less jumpy) if you just expanded the selected div to fill the window... umm if that is your intent.

Maybe you could change the demo I shared or describe what happens when a block is clicked upon.

Comment: This seems to be working well other than the vertical layout, and what do you mean by expanding the selected div to fill the window?
thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I mean instead of hiding all of the other divs, expand the selected div to fill the window. Kind of like what a light box would do: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Lightbox/